# Microsoft Edge and ActiveXObject("microsoft.xmldom") with JavaScript

Tags: ajax, microsoft-edge, xmldom

I understand Edge will no longer accept ActiveX controls. What replaces the old XMLDom object, using classic ASP?

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Edge you can use JQuery to manipulate Xml data.

See here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

JQuery can do much of what people used to build Active-X controls for.

Classic ASP is a server side scripting language framework that can generate any type of HTTP response to any browser much like PHP can. As a server side language framework that support multiple scripting languages such as JScript and VbScript I don't see how it is related to Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Classic ASP should have nothing to do with it but I wanted to let responders know where I was coming from so they would not offer other solutions which may be available through ASP.net.

Actually I have found my own answer. I didn't realize there is now  XMLHTTPRequest which pretty much takes the place of the old ActiveXObject("microsoft.xmldom") object, without causing security concerns based upon the use of ActiveX components on a web page.

Thanks for your help. Should anyone wish to see how I implemented it, just respond to this post. Otherwise, I bet I was the last developer on earth that didn't realize it existed and I don't want to take up space or waste your time.